# Best way to pop many elements from a Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code:

```
a = dict(aa='aaaa', bb='bbbbb', cc='ccccc', ...)
print(a.pop(['cc', ...]))
```

but this raises an error.
What is the best simple way to pop many elements from a python dictionary?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

How about the simple:

```
for e in ['cc', 'dd',...]: 
  a.pop(e)
```

Comment: That's a nice, simple and clean way to *remove* several elements. If you want to pop them, you'll probably find no simpler solution than to use pop in a list comprehension. While it's not exactly "hygienic", it is what he wanted ;)

Comment: If using `a.keys()` in the loop so as to not write out all the keys, make sure to use `list(a.keys())` otherwise it will complain.

Answer (score 38):

Using list comprehension:

```
a = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}
print [a.pop(key) for key in ['key1', 'key3']]
```

Comment: This works for me (thanks!) but I have a quick follow up question: isn't the result of a list comprehension a list? That would imply that your print statement would print a list containing a dict. But, this seems to deliver just the dict (i.e. the dict you started with minus the popped keys). Why? Thanks!

Comment: @Ben If you just use the print statement (so not a = [a.pop(key) ...]), the executed statement won't save the result in any variable, but the a.pop is still carried out. So the elements are popped out of a, but the result of that popping is not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly what you want, this should do the trick:

```
print [a.pop(k) for k in ['cc', ...]]
```

Be careful, though, because `pop` is destructive, i.e. it modifies your dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

I've peformed a benchmark:

```py
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
drop = ('a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

**Test 1**: `d.pop(k, None)`. Note the second argument: it makes sure that missing keys don't fail

```py
for key in drop:
    d.pop(key, None)
```

**Test 2**: `if key in d: d.pop()`. Will this extra condition slow things down or improve the performance of `.pop()`?

```py
for key in drop:
    if key in d:
        d.pop(key)
```

**Test 3**: bad set

```py
bad = set(d) & set(drop)  # find bad keys to drop

for key in bad:
    del d[key]
```

**Test 4**: create a new dict as comprehension

```py
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in drop}
```

Results:

- `.pop(key, None)`: 4.37s
- `if key in d: pop()`: 3.75s
- `if key in set(bad): del d[key]`: 5.27s
- comprehension: 7.2s

Conclusions:

- Dict comprehension has the worst performance
- `del` is not too good
- Both `.pop()` solutions are fine. Don't worry about an extra `if`: it actually improves things

Finally, Python is still able to 2 million times a second. Don't worry about it much :)

Answer (score 3):

```
a={'aa':'aaaa','bb':'bbbbb','cc':'ccccc'}
remove = ['aa', 'cc']
newA = dict([(k, v) for k,v in a.items() if k not in remove])
```

Comment: make `remove` a set, it will be quicker

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner, that will work on arbitrary long dictionary, for this exact case:

```
print([a.pop(key) for key in list(a.keys()) if key >= 'cc'])
```

---

To illustrate:

```
a = dict(aa='aaaa', bb='bbbbb', cc='ccccc', dd='ddddd', ee='eeeee')
print([a.pop(key) for key in list(a.keys()) if key >= 'cc']) # => ['ccccc', 'ddddd', 'eeeee']
print(a) # => {'aa': 'aaaa', 'bb': 'bbbbb'}
```

**Note**: it'll work as long as dictionary keys are "incremented" as follows: `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, `dd`, `ee`, `ff`, ...

Answer (score -1):

`your_dict.clear()` might also be an option