# Retain all entries except for one key python

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary. Just to give out context, I am trying to write my own simple cross validation unit.

So basically what I want is to get all the values except for the given keys.
And depending on the input, it returns all the values from a dictionary except to those what has been given.

So if the input is 2 and 5 then the output values doesn't have the values from the keys 2 and 5?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
for key, value in your_dict.items():
    if key not in your_blacklisted_set:
        print value
```

the beauty is that this pseudocode example is valid python code.

it can also be expressed as a list comprehension:

```
resultset = [value for key, value in your_dict.items() if key not in your_blacklisted_set]
```

Comment: Umm hi .. probably a dumb question.. but what would be my blacklisted set here?

Comment: [2, 5] in the example you've given, it's the list of keys you want to exclude.

Answer (score 27):

If your goal is to return a new dictionary, with all key/values except one or a few, use the following:

```
exclude_keys = ['exclude', 'exclude2']
new_d = {k: d[k] for k in set(list(d.keys())) - set(exclude_keys)}
```

where `'exclude'` can be replaced by (a list of) key(s) which should be excluded.

Comment: small improvement: initialize exclude_keys directly as a set: `exclude_keys = {'exclude', 'exclude2'}`

Answer (score 17):

Just for fun with sets

```
keys = set(d.keys())
excludes = set([...])

for key in keys.difference(excludes):
    print d[key]
```

Comment: `[d[k] for k in set(d.keys()).difference(set(excludes))]` don't use `dict` as a name.

Answer (score 17):

```
keys = ['a', 'b']
a_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
[a_dict.pop(key) for key in keys]
```

After popping out the keys to be discarded, a_dict will retain the ones you're after.

Comment: This was useful for me looking to remove one known key from a dict. If only one key then simply `dict.pop('key_name')` works. Needs try-catch if `key_name` might not exist.

Comment: Adding `None` as a second argument: `dict.pop('key_name', None)` solves the issue where the key doesn't exist. Thanks to @kolypto here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70785605/2523501

Answer (score 11):

Given a dictionary say

```
d = {
     2: 2, 5: 16, 6: 5,
     7: 6, 11: 17, 12: 9,
     15: 18, 16: 1, 18: 16,
     19: 17, 20: 10
     }
```

then the simple comprehension example would attain what you possibly desire

```
[v for k,v in d.iteritems() if k not in (2,5)]
```

This example lists all values not with keys {2,5}

for example the O/P of the above comprehension is

```
[5, 6, 1, 17, 9, 18, 1, 16, 17, 10]
```

Comment: Note: from python 3 `.iteritems()` was renamed `.items()`

``` [v for k,v in d.items() if k not in (2,5)]```

Answer (score 3):

Also, as a list comprehension using sets:

```
d = dict(zip(range(9),"abcdefghi"))
blacklisted = [2,5]
outputs = [d[k] for k in set(d.keys())-set(blacklisted)]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something along the following lines:

```
In [7]: d = dict((i,i+100) for i in xrange(10))

In [8]: d
Out[8]: 
{0: 100,
 1: 101,
 2: 102,
 3: 103,
 4: 104,
 5: 105,
 6: 106,
 7: 107,
 8: 108,
 9: 109}

In [9]: exc = set((2, 5))

In [10]: for k, v in d.items():
   ....:     if k not in exc:
   ....:         print v
   ....:         
   ....:         
100
101
103
104
106
107
108
109
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use pydash - https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from pydash import omit
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
c = omit(d, 'a')
print(c) # {'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

using exception handling

```
facebook_posts = [
    {'Likes': 21, 'Comments': 2}, 
    {'Likes': 13, 'Comments': 2, 'Shares': 1}, 
    {'Likes': 33, 'Comments': 8, 'Shares': 3}, 
    {'Comments': 4, 'Shares': 2}, 
    {'Comments': 1, 'Shares': 1}, 
    {'Likes': 19, 'Comments': 3}
]

total_likes = 0

for post in facebook_posts:
    try:
        total_likes = total_likes + post['Likes']
    except KeyError:
        pass
print(total_likes)
```

you can also use:

```
except KeyError: 'My Key'
```

but probably only good for once off use

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of using a shallow copy if you intend to modify the resulting dict.

```
import copy

def copy_dict_except_keys_shallow(d:dict, exclude_keys):
  return {k: d[k] for k in set(list(d.keys())) - set(exclude_keys)}

def copy_dict_except_keys_deep(d:dict, exclude_keys):
  return {k: copy.deepcopy(d[k]) for k in set(list(d.keys())) - set(exclude_keys)}

original = {'a': 1, 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
deep = copy_dict_except_keys_deep(original, ['a'])
deep['b'].append(4)

print("Modifying the deep copy preserves the original")
print(f"original: {original}")
print(f"deep copy: {deep}")
print()

shallow = copy_dict_except_keys_shallow(original, 'a')
shallow['b'].append(4)

print("Modifying the shallow copy changes the original")
print(f"original: {original}")
print(f"shallow copy: {shallow}")
```

```
Modifying the deep copy preserves the original
original: {'a': 1, 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
deep copy: {'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

Modifying the shallow copy changes the original
original: {'a': 1, 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
shallow copy: {'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:

```py
def dict_exclude_keys(d: dict, excludes: list[str]) -> dict:
    keys = set(list(d.keys())) - set(excludes)
    return {k: d[k] for k in keys if k in d}
```