# To reconstruct and change it to a form of one dictionary rather than two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the dictionary below:

```
dict_ex = {
        "coffee": "3",
        "milk": "7",
        "list": {
            "cola": "2",
            "juice": "1"
        }
    }
```

I would like to reconstruct it and change it to a form of one dictionary rather than two dictionaries:

```
dict_ex = {
     "coffee": "3",
     "milk": "7",
     "cola": "2",
     "juice": "1"
     }
```

I've revised this, so please check if this is right..
I would appreciate it if you could give me even a little advice.

Comment: What have you tried? Is there any code you can share?

Answer (score 4):

Update the original dictionary with the contents of the value of `list`:

```
>>> dict_ex.update(dict_ex["list"])
```

Then delete the `list` key from the dictionary:

```
>>> del dict_ex["list"]
```

Result:

```
>>> dict_ex
{'coffee': '3', 'milk': '7', 'cola': '2', 'juice': '1'}
```

Comment: `dict_ex.update(dict_ex.pop("list"))` also works.

Comment: @martineau Yes, that's basically the answer posted by Ch3steR

Comment: My point was that using `pop()` instead of `del` has the advantage that it would allow everything to be done in a single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) with [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)

- `dict.update(other)` from Docs:

  > Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from *other*, overwriting existing keys.
- `dict.pop(key)` from Docs:

  > If *key* is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value.

```
dict_ex.update(dict_ex.pop('list'))
print(dict_ex)
# {'coffee': '3', 'milk': '7', 'cola': '2', 'juice': '1'}
```

---

As an aside, if you don't want to update the original dict. We can use dict comp with union<sup>1</sup> shorthand.

### `Python >= 3.9`

```
out = {k: dict_ex[k] for k in dict_ex.keys()-['list']} | dict_ex['list']
```

### `Python <= 3.8`

There's are SO posts [Retain all entries except for one key python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8717395/12416453) and [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (take union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/12416453)

```
out = { **{k: dict_ex[k] for k in dict_ex.keys()-['list']}, **dict_ex['list'] }
```

---

1. From Docs

- `d | other`

  > Create a new dictionary with the merged keys and values of d and other, which must both be dictionaries. The values of other take priority when d and other share keys.
  > New in version 3.9.